# Get All Row ID for Specific Product

Tags: magento2, magento-ee

In Magento 2.4.4 EE we have staging feature which we can schedule some changes on products

If product is scheduled for change it creates a new row on catalog_product_entity
so for example for product id 100

we have 2 rows
row_id 100
and
row_id 101

how to retrieve the two row_id for product id 100
tried product collection but it retrieve the latest (active) row_id only which is 101

For example

```
/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $productCollection */
$productCollection = $productCollectionFactory->create();

$entityId = 100;

$productCollection->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', $entityId);
$productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('row_id');

foreach ($productCollection as $item) {
    echo $item->getRowId;
}
```